# How to prove or disprove the convergence of the series $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{(-1)^n\cdot a_{n}}{n}$?

Tags: sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence

**Question:**

> Assume that $a_{n}\in\mathbb R$, and let the series $$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}a_{n}$$
>   be convergent

I would like to prove or disprove the convergence of
$$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\dfrac{(-1)^n\cdot a_{n}}{n}.$$

If $$a_{n}=\dfrac{1}{n^p},p>1,$$

It is clear that the series $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\dfrac{(-1)^n\cdot a_{n}}{n}$ is  convergent.

Comment: Got something from an answer below?

Answer (score 3):

This is false. Take $a_n=\frac{(-1)^n}{\log(n)}$. The first series converge by alternating series test, but the second diverges by Cauchy condensation test. See here for what I mean for Cauchy condensation: [Convergence of series involving in iterated logarithms $\sum \frac{1}{n(\log n)^{\alpha_1}\cdots (\log^k(n))^{\alpha_k} }$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/655240/convergence-of-series-involving-in-iterated-logarithms-sum-frac1n-log-n)

Answer (score 1):

If $a_n$ is a positive-valued succession, then:
$$\left|\frac{(-1)^na_n}{n}\right|=\frac{|a_n|}{n}=\frac{a_n}{n}\leq a_n,$$
thus the modified series converges by the comparison test. However, in general, this may not hold. If $a_n$ converges absolutely, the argument still holds. Otherwise, it depends on the form of $a_n$, as shown by the example in the other answer, where $a_n=\frac{(-1)^n}{\log(n)}$ converges by the Leibniz test, whereas $\frac{(-1)^na_n}{n}=\frac{1}{\log(n)}$ diverges, for which cfr [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/655240/convergence-of-series-involving-in-iterated-logarithms-sum-frac1n-log-n), all those convergences meant as series, not as successions.

Comment: @boywholived I'm not sure what you mean. You can always edit things. In any case, my answer first deals with the case $a_n\geq0$, then giving the displayed equation, and then does what it can about the general case, so I don't really see what would need to be corrected. It is clear that, in the question, the statement "If $a_n=$" etc holds if $|a_n|=\frac{1}{n^p}$.